# Identify NSoperation dynamically

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsoperation

How to identify Nsoperation dynamically.

I am creating a NSoperation subclass

```
- (id)initWithConnectDevice:(ConnectDevice *)cDevice toPeripheral:(CBPeripheral*)peripheral oPerationIndex:(int) index{

if (self = [super init]) {

    operationIndex = index;
    executing = NO;
    finished = NO;
    self.connectDevice = cDevice;
    [self.connectDevice setDelegate:self];
    self.connectedPeripheral = peripheral;
}
return self;
```

}

```
-(BOOL)isConcurrent{
return YES;
}
- (BOOL)isExecuting {
return executing;
}

- (BOOL)isFinished {
return finished;
}

-(void) terminateOperation {
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
finished = YES;
executing = NO;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}

- (void)start {

@autoreleasepool {

    if (self.isCancelled){

        [timer invalidate];
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        finished = YES;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        return;
    }

      timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self   selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

}
}

 -(void)timerFired:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"timerFired");

}
```

I am scanning for BLE devices. For example I will found 3 devices, 3 buttons will create.

I am calling this class every time when I am clicking on that button.That means, When I click on button, I am connecting to bluetooth device and get the data from that device for every second thats why I am using timer in **start** method.

Like that I have multiple bluetooth devices, whenever I clicked on button, I want to create multiple instances of **Operation Queue** class.

Now, I want to identify which data is coming from which thread.
Could you please help me....

This the way I am calling above class from viewcontroller

```
 OperationQueue *queue = [[OperationQueue alloc] initWithConnectDevice:connectDevices      toPeripheral:peripheral oPerationIndex:operationIndex];
queue.delegate = self;

[[[AppDelegate app] mainQueue] addOperation:queue];
operationIndex = operationIndex+1;
```

Comment: What is OperationQueue? Is that your NSOperation subclass? That's a poor choice of name given that there is an NSOperation class.

Comment: Also, what is the `mainQueue` you're adding these things to?

Comment: Yes. That is Nsoperation subclass. Sorry for that. I will change the class name

Comment: main queue is NSOperationQueue object and created in Appdelegate

Comment: That's also a bit confusing since the main queue is also a well-defined concept (it's the UI queue). One more question - when is it that you actually need to get data out? You've shown how you start these operations, but nothing appears to happen in them, so it's not clear where the problem is. Can you explain what it is you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your operations has two identifying properties already - the connected device and the index. When the timer fires, depending what you want to do with the data, you can use these properties to tell where the data is coming from.

You can either have a delegate property on the operation, where a delegate method is called when the timer fires that takes the device and the received data as parameters, or you the operation could have a block property, which takes a block to be executed whenever data is received - the block would have the device and the received data as parameters.

Assuming you want to update the UI when the data is received, be sure to call the delegate method or execute the block on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks alot . But how can I check with those two properties in viewcontroller class dynamically.

Comment: For example, some temp is coming from each device for every second. How can I take those values and display, it means I want to take an array for every device.I m totally confused. Please help me ....

Comment: In the delegate method, you'd take the value and use it to update a label. You'd know which label to update because you're also passing the index or the device. If you want to show a list of values then yes, you'd need an array per device.

Comment: I am creating a delegate in the timer, but in viewcontroller new device is overriding the old device. How can i get both devices in the view controller delegate method.

Comment: I don't know, you haven't shown any code like that.